# "grunt lesslint" task not recognizing variables from imports

Tags: compiler-errors, less, gruntjs, lint

To preface, I am new to Grunt so forgive me for my general clumsiness with it.

I am trying to use the [grunt-lesslint](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/grunt-lesslint) Grunt plugin but it is failing. My problem is when running the `grunt lesslint` task on my less files, it does not recognize variables and mixins from imported files.

E.g.,

```
Error parsing app/_less/footer.less
.text-muted is undefined
Error parsing app/_less/navbar.less
variable @navbar-height is undefined
```

My `Grunfile.coffee` states:

```
lesslint:
  src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/_less/**/*.less']
```

Essentially, my file structure is like so:

```
├── _less/
│   ├── app.less
│   ├── navbar.less
│   └── footer.less
└── bootstrap/
    └── bootstrap.less
```

Now here's `app.less`:

```
@import "../bootstrap/bootstrap.less";  # Variables & Mixins
@import "navbar";
@import "footer";
```

And, in the case of verbosity, here's the snippet from `footer.less`:

```
#footer {
  .text-muted();
}
```

`.text-muted`, along with all other variables and mixins, is defined within the **bootstrap** import. The LESS compiles fine and does not throw an error, so I am trying to figure out if this is an issue with my code or if this is an issue I need to bring up with **grunt-lesslint**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `Gruntfile.coffee` to include

```
lesslint:
    src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/_less/app.less']
    options:
        imports: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/_less/*.less']
```

That way app.less will be linted and any less files it imports from the same folder.

This means that they are linted as imports and should know about bootstraps mixins

Answer (score 2):

Commenting on what [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745309/ben) stated previously: adding:

```
@import "../bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
```

to footer.less and should indeed solve your problem. When grunt-lesslint attempts to lint footer.less, it *only* lints footer.less and and all files imported into it. It doesn't know to check it's parent file (in this case app.less) for variable declarations.

You can re-import as many files as you like, as long as the import tree is a directed acyclic graph. Less knows to only include them once in your final minified css.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to be more explicit with your `@import` declarations. Try adding `@import "../bootstrap/bootstrap.less";` to the top of your navbar/footer files; what I assume is happening is that bootstrap is getting compiled down to CSS in your `app.less` file, so when it tries to parse the other files it doesn't have the mixins anymore.

You'll need to do this for each file that needs the bootstrap mixins.

Comment: Although I'm certain that would work, the Less documentation [states](http://lesscss.org/#-importing) that _"Content of imported LESS file is copied into importing style sheet and compiled together with it. Importing and imported files share all mixins, namespaces, variables and other structures."_

Also, this would then, I assume, needlessly duplicate the bootstrap code multiple times.

Comment: Just re-read your question again, my answer doesn't solve it sorry (had thought you wanted less compilation which isn't the case). The only issue that may be kind of relevant is this one https://github.com/kevinsawicki/grunt-lesslint/issues/3 but also note on the main page "By default the plugin uses the less and csslint config settings to configure the LESS parser and the CSS Lint validator.". Perhaps this option is of more use: https://github.com/kevinsawicki/grunt-lesslint#less - specify an array of imports in your Gruntfile and see if that fixes things. :-)